# ListView.builder's builder items are overflowing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the ListView.builder() to display my list items but the items inside a fixed container are overflowing and I'm not sure how to fix this. This is the behavior I'm getting:

[image]

The highlighted area is the area where the items are overflowing. This is the code for the ListView:

```
Container(
                        height: size.height * .3,
                        child: Consumer<TodoProvider>(
                          builder: (context, todoProvider, child) {
                            return todoProvider.getTodos.length == 0
                                ? Center(
                                    child: Text('Your todos will appear here!'),
                                  )
                                : ListView.builder(
                                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    itemCount: todoProvider.getTodos.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      // if element is not the first and the last then add padding
                                      return (index != 0 &&
                                              index !=
                                                  todoProvider.getTodos.length -
                                                      1)
                                          ? Padding(
                                              padding:
                                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 5),
                                              child: CustomListTile(todoProvider
                                                  .getTodos[index].title),
                                            )
                                          : CustomListTile(todoProvider
                                              .getTodos[index].title);
                                    },
                                  );
```

debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;

[image]

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: overflowing? what do you mean by that? post your screenshot again when you set `debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;` inside `main()`

Comment: @pskink I have added the output. Please have a look.

Comment: so what is overflowing? last item ("d") is clipped by a "Completed tasks" container and i dont see any "overflow"

Comment: 'd' is not the last item here. Please focus on the red highlighted area. There you will find a ListTile with a white background behind the text 'Completed tasks'. That tile is containing a title but the title is not visible when the item crosses that height but the background is still visible. Let me change the tile color and then you will find out what I'm talking about.

Comment: @pskink please have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the ListTile inside a card fixed the issue for me. This is how it looks now:

[image]